# gcc C17 return from incompatible pointer type

Tags: arrays, c, implicit-conversion, c-strings, function-declaration

```
char *funArr(char *s[]){
    return s;
}


int main(void){ 
    char *s[] = {"a","b"};
    char *r = funArr(s);
    printf("%s",r[0]);
}
```

I can't get an array from a function correctly. I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I'm just getting started with C, can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

So this function declaration

```
char *funArr(char *s[]){
```

is adjusted by the compiler to

```
char *funArr(char **s){
```

As you see the parameter `s` has the type `char **`. If you want to return this pointer then the function return type shall be `char **`.

```
char ** funArr(char *s[]){
```

So in main you need to write

```
char **r = funArr(s);
printf("%s",r[0]);
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char ** funArr( char *s[] )
{
    return s;
}


int main(void)
{ 
    char * s[] = { "a", "b" };
    
    char **r = funArr( s );
    
    puts( r[0] );
}
```

The program output is

```
a
```